# div not fitting to its contents

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

So I have a div inside a div. The content in the child div needs to be text-aligned left and the child div itself needs to be centered within the parent div. My problem is, I can't get the child div to only be the width of its content so I can center it. It keeps stretching the length of the parent div. I've tried display:inline-block, inline, table. nothing is working. How do I get the child div to be centered within the parent, but have the child div content be aligned to the left?

Here is my code.
HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="sub_gallery">
        <a class="image" href="pic1.jpg"><img src="pic1.jpg"></a>
        <a class="image" href="pic1.jpg"><img src="pic1.jpg"></a>
        <a class="image" href="pic1.jpg"><img src="pic1.jpg"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.gallery {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.sub_gallery {
    padding:6px;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.image {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:6px;
}

.image img {
    position:absolute;
    top:-10000px;
    bottom:-10000px;
    left:-10000px;
    right:-10000px;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is a simple diagram of what I want it to look like:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Q0a.png)

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/s9x09xna/2/ ] ary you looking like this one ??

Comment: I put your code into a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGrWJm It looks exactly as you describe the desired result(?)

Comment: @MostafaBaezid In opening that code-runner [jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/s9x09xna/2], You see that the width of the child div (red div) is as wide as its parent div (black div). I need the child div to be as wide as its content and centered within the parent, while at the same time is aligning the images within it to the left. Am I making sense?

Comment: @BradonThomason accroding to your diagram [ https://jsfiddle.net/s9x09xna/3/ ] you can resize the result area and check .

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes things quite different but try it. I am quite sure this will help because it centers the images perfectly on the page.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="gallery">
<div class="sub_gallery">
<center>
<a href="pic1.jpg"><img class="image" src="pic1.jpg"></a>
<a href="pic1.jpg"><img class="image" src="pic1.jpg"></a>
<a href="pic1.jpg"><img class="image" src="pic1.jpg"></a>
...
</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.sub_gallery {
    padding:6px;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
}

.image {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:6px;
}

.image img {
    position:absolute;
    top:-10000px;
    bottom:-10000px;
    left:-10000px;
    right:-10000px;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

I hope this was helpful.